# Can I automate ssh connection? ssh user@server.company.com

Tags: shell, networking, ssh, remote-access, remote-server

I want to create a script that inserting a new connection to my `known_hosts` file.

When I want to add a new server to the known_hosts file I manually use this command:

```
ssh user@server.company.com
```

Then I get this in return:

```
The authenticity of host 'server.company.com (XX.34.228.XXX)' can't be established.
ECDSA key fingerprint is 78:eb:28:7c:a6:19:4f:28:48:ab:0d:c6:e4:4e:dc:ff.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?
```

when answering 'yes'

I get this in return:

> Warning: Permanently added 'server.company.com XX.34.228.XXX' (ECDSA)
>   to the list of known hosts. user@server.company.com's password:

After printing the password - I'm connected to the remote server.

The next time I would like to connect, I won't be needing to insert the password again.

Is there a way to automate this process using a shell script?
I tried all those options with no luck:

```
yes | ssh user@server.company.com

echo yes | ssh user@server.company.com
```

but nothing works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to create a script that inserting a new connection to my known_hosts file ...

There is `ssh-keyscan` for that:

```
ssh-keyscan server.company.com >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
```

But note that this is the only security check against MitM attack so unless you are really sure that there can be nothing wrong between you and the server, you should manually check the stored public key before connecting to the server.

To automate the password insertion, you can use `sshpass`:

```
sshpass -p password ssh user@server.company.com
```

but that is certainly not advised, since the password is stored in the plaintext.

Comment: That's working, and It solved the known_hosts issue,
In order to complete the automation I need to be able to insert the password when I get prompted.

Comment: this is what I get:
echo password | ssh user@server.company.com
Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.
server.company.com password: